# concentration inequality question

Tags: probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

Suppose that $g_1,\dots,g_m$ are i.i.d. $N(0,I_n)$ vectors. Let
$$
X = \sum_{i\neq j} (\langle g_i,g_j \rangle^2 - n)
$$
It is known that when $m\to \infty$, $n\to\infty$, $m/n\to 0$,
$$
\frac{1}{2mn}X \to N(0,1) \quad \text{in distribution}.
$$
My question is, how can we obtain a concentration bound for $X$, maybe something like $\Pr\{X > tmn\} \leq \exp(-ct^2)$? Is this possible?